# What does もらえる mean in this sentence ?

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs, giving-and-receiving

Here's an excerpt from the article I am reading ([link](https://niseco.hatenablog.jp/entry/2015/08/19/%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%8C%E8%AA%AD%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E9%96%93%E9%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E9%9D%A2%E7%99%BD%E3%81%84%E3%81%8A%E3%81%99%E3%81%99%E3%82%81%E5%B0%8F%E8%AA%AC%E3%83%99%E3%82%B9) to the article):

> あくまで私の個人的な評価ではありますが、この中からあなたのお気に入りの本がきっと見つかるはずですよ！また、**今回取り上げる本は文庫版がほとんどなので気軽に買って読んでもらえる作品ばかりです**。

Last line is where I am stuck at. I understand it as,

'*Most of the books I am going to introduce this time are paperbacks which can be casually bought and read anywhere*'

What I don't understand is the もらえる at the end. Is it there only for politeness or does it have any nuance ?

Would the last sentence make sense without the もらえる、

> **今回取り上げる本は文庫版がほとんどなので気軽に買って読める作品ばかりです。**

Comment: Yes, it's keigo, and is ok without もらえる

Answer (score 3, accepted):

もらえる is the potential form of the [subsidiary-verb もらう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/308/5010). This もらう implies the action of 読む is somehow beneficial to the speaker, i.e., the author of this article would be happy if someone took a look at his review, bought the book and read it. In this case, such a nuance is not essential, and it can be safely omitted without largely changing the meaning. もらう itself has nothing to do with keigo, but maybe the sentence would look slightly more friendly with もらえる because of how it indicates a connection between the author and the readers.

Answer (score 1):

It's only for politeness.

It's OK if you do it or not.