# How to interpret "あとはかってにちゅうもんしてくれりゃ"?

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, contractions

I learn Japanese by watching 深夜食堂 myself. In the introduction of an episode, the main character says "あとはかってにちゅうもんしてくれりゃ".

I am able to figure out the meaning of the whole sentence by watching translated subtitle. However, I have no idea when and how to use the phrase "してくれりゃ".

So, what is the modality when you use "してくれりゃ"? How to use it correctly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

くれ**りゃ** is a colloquial, contracted pronunciation of くれ**れば**.

For this kind of contraction, see this thread:

- [What is the meaning of りゃ in this phrase?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12524/9831)

注文してくれれば breaks down to...

> 注文して -- "order", the て-form of the する-verb 「注文する」
>   くれれば* -- "if you do ~~ (for me)", the conditional form of the subsidiary verb 「くれる」
>   <sup>(*ば is a conjunctive particle)</sup>

For more on the subsidiary verb くれる:

- [Differences between くれます, もらいます and いただきます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/260/9831)

So the sentence literally means:

> あとは、[勝手]{かって}に[注文]{ちゅうもん}してくれりゃ、～～
>   "Other than that, if you order as you like, then~~"

---

This contraction (eba→ya) might sound a bit masculine/rough. A few examples...

> 「そうならそうと、最初から言って**くれりゃ**いいじゃねえか。」
>   「払うもん払って**くれりゃ**、もう用はねえよ。」