# What do よって and りゃあ mean in this sentence?

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions, particle-って

Here is the sentence. It's from a show called midnight diner, its right at the beginning. It's like an intro that plays at the beginning of every episode. I kinda get the gist of what it says but these two specific words confuse me.

> あとは勝手に注文してくれりゃあ、できるもんなら作るよってのが俺の営業方針さ。

Any help is appreciated.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74320/9831

Answer (score 1):

It means:

> 『あとは勝手に注文してくれ**れば**、できるものなら作る**よ』という**のが俺の営業方針さ。 "Other than these (things/dishes), if you just order what you want, I will make/cook what I can" is my business policy.

りゃあ is a colloquial contracted pronunciation of れば.

Related thread: [What is the meaning of りゃ in this phrase?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12524/9831)

---

The よって is 「～よ。」って = 「～よ。」という. The よ is a sentence ending particle, and the って is a colloquial version of という. From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/#jn-147762):

> って
> 1⃣［格助詞］
> ２ 上の語または文が、次に来る語の内容説明であることを表す。…**という**。「山田様**って**方ご存じですか」「用**って**ほどじゃない」